# Docusign anchor tab positioning is incorrect

Tags: docusignapi

Using the API I am creating a new document with 2 embedded signers. The anchor tabs I am defining are hardcoded and are all set with an x offset of 3.5cms.

However the formatting is completely off. Can anyone help me understand why that is?

[image]

Also the labels that I am defining for each entry field are not visible. Any reason why that is?

```
array("anchorString" => $tabArray['counterSignDate'],
                                "anchorXOffset"             => "3.5",
                                "anchorYOffset"             => "0",                                
                                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent"  => "true",
                                "anchorUnits"               => "cms")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like the offset is set relevant to the beginning of the anchorString! Not very clear in the API!

https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/Content/Sending%20Group/Using%20Anchor%20Tags.htm